# how to display 2 different buttons instead of the notification close and view button in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am creating an alarm app by making of use of local notification.when i select a particular time from my date picker and click on the save button my notification gets set at that particular time.This has been done and i get the notification at proper time that i have set.but the problem is when my app is not running i get notification with 2 buttons i.e one for close and other for view details .when i click on close button my notification close and when the view details button is clicked it takes me to my app.But actually i dont't need this. i want in place of close button snooze button should be present and in place of view button stop button should appear. i.e when my alarm notification is fired i want that in place of close and view button stop and snooze button should appear.When i click on stop button alarm should get stopped and when the snooze button is clicked the alarm is delayed for 5 mins.Please help me in solving my problem.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The alert displayed by a push/local notification has either one (OK) button, or two buttons - the left button is always "Close" and the right button is either "View" or a string (for `action-loc-key`) you supply in the dictionary for the `alert` key of your payload.

The functionality you require isn't available using the notification alerts directly. Maybe your app could "snooze" by default (i.e. when the close button is pressed - so unless the app is started the alarm plays again after 5 minutes). If the user presses the View button (maybe re-titled "Cancel Alarm") the app starts and the alarm is cancelled.

See **The Notification Payload** in
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html